# old() value function using data from database not working in Blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, database

I have a form with 4 input fields, all of them to which I applied an `old()` function so whenever users load the page after submitting the form, the data that they filled in would retain in the fields for better UX.

My issue is that out of these 4 fields, only 1 has the `old()` function working. The difference between this field and the others is that:

1. The name and id attributes for this field are the same, while other fields have different names and IDs respectively.
2. The `input` type for this field is `type="number"` while the other fields are `type="text"`.

Based on these differences, I tried modifying the code to standardize them, and only one solution works which is that I change the `input` types to `"number"`, however, not all my inputs are numbers, so it is not an ideal solution.

Form blade file:

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emp_name" id="company_name"
      value="{{ old('emp_name' , (isset($user->emp_detail->emp_name) ? $user->emp_detail->emp_name : old('emp_name')) ) }}">
   @if ($errors->has('emp_name'))
   <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('emp_name') }}</span>
   @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" name="emp_length" id="emp_length"
      value="{{ old('emp_length' , (isset($user->emp_detail->emp_length) ? $user->emp_detail->emp_length : old('emp_length')) ) }}">
   @if ($errors->has('emp_length'))
   <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('emp_length') }}</span>
   @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
   <input type="text" class="form-control money-prefix" name="emp_monthly_gross_salary" id="monthly_salary"
      value="{{ old('emp_monthly_gross_salary' , (isset($user->emp_detail->emp_monthly_gross_salary) ? $user->emp_detail->emp_monthly_gross_salary : old('emp_monthly_gross_salary')) ) }}">
   @if ($errors->has('emp_monthly_gross_salary'))
   <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('emp_monthly_gross_salary') }}</span>
   @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
   <input type="text" class="form-control money-prefix" name="monthly_allowance" id="bonus"
      value="{{ old('monthly_allowance' , (isset($user->emp_detail->emp_monthly_allowance) ? $user->emp_detail->emp_monthly_allowance : old('monthly_allowance')) ) }}">
   @if ($errors->has('monthly_allowance'))
   <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('monthly_allowance') }}</span>
   @endif
</div>
```

To be clear, I also have several other forms in which I applied the same `old()` function, with texts as well as numbers, and they work fine, so I am unsure why the `old()` function won't work on this form specifically. I also `dd()` the variables I wanted to output as the old function, so I am sure my controller is already passing the values, my blade just isn't showing it.

Can anyone advise me on this problem?

Comment: So is it only the "old" values that are not appearing (i.e. the ones from the previous submission)? Do the default values appear (the 2nd parameter of the `old` function)?

Comment: @apokryfos both of them don't work, the fields remain empty when i go back to the page, except for the emp_length field

Comment: @yyyyuyu Plz try `old('emp_monthly_gross_salary' , optional($user->emp_detail)->emp_monthly_gross_salary)` and let me know it's work or not. No need to call `old` again

Comment: hi @ThanhDao i tried the code but it still won't work :/

Answer (score 0):

maybe the issue is the default value, may be set but empty
try to check it with old directly without the default value
ex:
replace

```
{{ old('emp_name' , (isset($user->emp_detail->emp_name) ? $user->emp_detail->emp_name : old('emp_name')) ) }}
```

with

```
{{ old('emp_name') }}
```

if it works fine with you then you need to enhance the default value condition
ie:  `(isset($user->emp_detail->emp_name) ? $user->emp_detail->emp_name : old('emp_name')`

Comment: I tried putting {{ old('emp_name') }} as my value and submitted the form, then went back to the page and it still doesn't work, does that mean there is a problem with my default value?

Comment: make sure to add ->withInput() to go back with data 
ex: 
`return redirect('form')->withInput();`

Comment: also, make sure that you added `$request->flash();`  to flash the current input to the session so that it is available during the user's next request